# How do I generate presigned links with the NodeJS SDK for IBM Cloud Object Storage?

Tags: node.js, security, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'm using IBM Cloud Object Storage and its NodeJS SDK (https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-js).

I want to generate presigned links so that users can access contents in the bucket without the need to authenticate.

When I call `cos.getSignedUrl('getObject', ...)`, I get the error `UnsupportedSigner: Presigning only supports S3 or SigV4 signing.`

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to generate HMAC keys for your service instance as described in [How do I create HMAC credentials for IBM Cloud Object Storage using the CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632767/how-do-i-create-hmac-credentials-for-ibm-cloud-object-storage-using-the-cli)

Once you have the HMAC access key and secret access key, change the initialization of the COS SDK as follow:

```
const config = {
  endpoint: 'cos endpoint',
  apiKeyId: 'cos api key',
  ibmAuthEndpoint: 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
  serviceInstanceId: 'cos crn'
  // these two are required to generate presigned URLs
  credentials: new COS.Credentials('<access key>', '<secret_access_key>', sessionToken = null),
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
};
const cos = new COS.S3(config);
```

then you can generate presigned links with:

```
const url = await cos.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: '<your-bucket-name>',
  Key: '<your-key-name>',
  Expires: 60 * 5, // 5 minutes
});
```