# IBM Cloud: How to create HMAC credentials for COS using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, object-storage, terraform-provider-ibm

I am using IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS) to store files on IBM Cloud. I have used Terraform to provision the service and to create the storage bucket. How can I create credentials including the HMAC portion using Terraform?

This is how to create the resource key (credentials):

```
# service access key for COS
resource "ibm_resource_key" "MyCos" {
  name                 = "my-accKey-cos"
  role                 = "Writer"
  resource_instance_id = ibm_resource_instance.cos.id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to creating HMAC credentials is to have the right parameters for  [**ibm_resource_key**](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-resource-mgmt-resources#resource-key).

```
# service access key for COS
resource "ibm_resource_key" "MyCos" {
  name                 = "my-accKey-cos"
  role                 = "Writer"
  resource_instance_id = ibm_resource_instance.cos.id
  parameters           = { HMAC = true }
}
```

With the added parameter for HMAC it works.

[In that sense it is similar to using the CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632767/how-do-i-create-hmac-credentials-for-ibm-cloud-object-storage-using-the-cli).